# How do I copy/clone a dynamic disk in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, clone, dynamic-disk

I have some dynamic disks (or "partitions" but they are not really partitions) that I want to copy onto spare hard drives.

I tried using gpartd (and fdisk for that matter) from a linux live disc. All it saw was hard drives with only one partition encasing the whole hard drive. So gpartd/fdisk is incapable of identifying the dynamic "partitions" and allowing me to copy them.

Any tools that can be used to clone/copy a dynamic "partition"? (I'm open to commercial software suggestions if they can do the job)...

Comment: Bumping; surely someone has made a clone of a dynamic disk partition before?

Comment: Bumping again. Surely someone has made a clone of a dynamic disk partition before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EASEUS Partition Master Home Edition](http://www.partition-tool.com/copy-wizard/)(free) comes with their Disk & Partition Copy Wizard, which is able to [Copy Dynamic Volumes](http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/copy-dynamic-volume.htm)

[Norton Ghost](http://www.symantec.com/norton/ghost)($69.99) should get the job done, If EASEUS doesn't work.

Edit:

Here's some [reviews](http://download.cnet.com/Easeus-Partition-Master-Home-Edition/3640-2248_4-11234487.html) of EASEUS Partition Master Home Edition

Comment: I tried this and also MiniTool home edition. None can copy dynamic volumes. I guess I have shell out $$ to buy something.

Comment: OP was requesting how to clone disk. EASEUS cannot clone dynamic disks, just verified it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [Acronis True Image Workstation](http://www.acronis.com/backup-recovery/workstation/).  There is a good review [here](http://www.techsupportalert.com/drive-imaging-reviews.htm).

True Image does [support dynamic disks](http://kb.acronis.com/content/1568), but read the fine print.  Also, it's not clear to me that you could (for example) choose a single logical volume.

Answer (score 0):

Acronis's True Image Home 2010 with the "Plus Pack" supports dynamic disks (and RAID arrays, for that matter) even from a boot CD

Comment: According to some anonymous user, this might not work, only for basic-to-basic copying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the freeware [Partition Wizard Home Edition 8.1.1](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) to clone Windows Dynamic Disk (e.g. raid 0).

1. initialize blank drive with MBR in diskmgmt.msc
2. use the wizard in Partition Wizard and choose one primary partition. Don't  forget to "apply changes"
3. open diskmgmt.msc, take the dynamic disk offline and assign its drive letter to newly created partition, which then becomes immediately usable in Windows Explorer